# Request Object to res.render error Usando Express y handlebars y passport

Tags: nodejs, express, passport, handlebars.js

recientemente me encuentro con un problema que no me queda muy claro como resolver, tengo mi servidor NodeJs construido con Express , actualmente la autenticacion la manejo con passport , y tengo que editar los datos del usuario logueado , aqui es donde tengo problemas.

Inicialmente tengo esta función que me retorna a la vista de editar perfil , en el req que le paso a la función si doy un console.log(req.user) puedo ver el JSON con los datos del usuario autenticado , pero al intentar pasar estos datos al template hecho con handlebars me tira el siguiente error

```
console.log(req.user)
{
[0]   _id: 6088f376f715bf3be09054c9,
[0]   name: 'Rodrigo A',
[0]   email: 'email@gmail.com',
[0]   password: '$2b$12$29LZoX0dI7iDFpjAih0PtOGWQch5OkxHdI1hy2gdYs2cRsf5Aw8DS',
[0]   __v: 0
[0] }
```

```
exports.formEditUser =  ( req , res ) =>{

      res.render('edit-profile',{
      namePage: 'Edita tu perfil',
      user : req.user
   })
}
```

Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "name" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.

Regularmente este error me tira al hacer consultas en mongodb y tratar de pasar los datos a la vista sin agregarle al final de la consulta .lean() , pero esta ocasión es diferente
, cabe mencionar que tanto la configuración de passport como la configuración de handlebars funciona correctamente , podrían orientarme u indicarme como podria pasar estos datos a esta vista por favor , se los agradeceria mucho

```
/**importamos mongoose  */
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
/**Importamos las configuraciones de mongodb */
require('./config/db');
/**Importamos express */
const express = require('express');
/**Importar Handlebars */
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
/**Importar Path para obtener la url actual del proyecto */
const path = require('path');
/**Importar el router */
const router = require('./routes');
/** */
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
/** */
const session = require('express-session');
/** */
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
/** Importar flash para mostrar msjs de validación */
const flash = require('connect-flash');
/**Importar configuraciones de passport */
const passport = require('./config/passport');


/**leer las variables del envirenment */
require('dotenv').config({ path : '.env'});

/**guardamos express en una constante */
const app = express();
/**Permite leer los campos  */
app.use(express.json());
/**para poder leer el cuerpo de una solicitud*/
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));


/**Habilitar handlebars como view */
app.engine('handlebars',
   exphbs({
       defaultLayout: 'layout',
       helpers: require('./helpers/handlebars')
   })
);

app.set('view engine','handlebars');

/**archivos staticos */
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    key: process.env.KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create(mongoose.connection)
}));

//inicializar passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Aletas y flash messages
app.use(flash());

//crear nuestro middleware
app.use( (req , res , next) =>{
  res.locals.msgs = req.flash();
  next();
});


app.use('/',router());

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

aquí la respuesta del porque el error que presente. Por razones de seguridad, handlebars no permite pasar el resultado obtenido directamente , es decir el objeto con los datos antes presentados en el problema. Lo que hice para que no se transfieran datos confidenciales fue crear un nuevo objeto solamente agregando los datos necesarios para la edición del usuario. Esto teniendo la versión "express-handlebars": "^5.0.0".

quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
exports.formEditUser = ( req , res ) =>{
      const userAutenticate = req.user;
      const newObject = {
           name: userAutenticate.name,
           email: userAutenticate.email
      }
      res.render('edit-profile',{
      nombrePagina: 'Edita tu perfil en devJobs',
      user : newObject
   })
}
```